# MySQL to AppEngine

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine, bulk-load

I'm from Brazil and study at FATEC (college located in Brazil).
I'm trying to learn about AppEngine.
Now, I'm trying to load a large database from MySQL to AppEngine to perform some queries, but I don't know how i can do it. I did some testing with CSV files,but is there any way to perform the direct import from MySQL?
This database is from Pentaho BI Server (www.pentaho.com).
Thank you for your attention.

Regards,
Daniel Naito

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear from your tags, but the [documented bulkloader](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) is preferable to trying to hoist your csv files directly to the app-server.

Answer (score 1):

[Advanced Bulk Loading](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Advanced-Bulk-Loading-part-3-Alternate-datasources) by Nick Johnson is what you are looking for.

If you need live synchronization between App Engine and MySQL, you should look into [AppRocket](http://code.google.com/p/approcket/). AppRocket seems to require that you have your data in App Engine before the first synchronization. It will also require some minor changes to your model.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Pentaho BI Server as your data source, why don't you consider using Pentaho Data Integration (ETL tool) to move the data over? At the very least PDI automate any movement of data between your data source and any AppEngine bulk loader tool (it can easily trigger any app with a shell step).